# Why Vue web component styles are not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-component, vue-cli-3

I'm new to Vue and i've built a card game with Vue and Buefy which contains 4 components each of them having their own styles and functionalities. I want my entirely application to be builted into one single Web Component (because it will be embedded in several pages).

## Expected Behavior

`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name card-game ./src/App.vue` applies all of my custom styles and Buefy styles just like other commands such as `npm run serve` and `npm run build`.

[Buefy and custom styles working (ie: responsivity, modal css, etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TlNV.jpg)

## Current Behavior

`vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component ./src/App.vue` applies some styles and other don't.

[Styles not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UGVN.jpg)

### Basic Folder Structure

```sh
MyApp
└── src
    ├── assets
    ├── components
    │   └── Card.vue
    │   └── CardModal.vue
    │   └── CardCollapse.vue
    │   └── Deck.vue
    └── App.vue
```

#### App.vue

```html
<template>
    
  <section class="section">

      <Deck/>

  </section>

</template>
```

```js
<script>
  
  import Deck from './Deck';

  export default {

    name: 'CardGame',
      components: {
            
        Deck

      }
  
    }

</script>
```

```css
<style lang="scss">

  //In App.vue styles i have all my global styles/utils which i use in other components

  //Importing font and buefy
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
  @import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy-build";

  //My utils
  ....

</style>
```

Comment: Check this - https://vuidget.netlify.app/

Comment: @IVOGELOV It worked, thanks man!